# ggplot2 plot does not plot the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the two dataframes I have, yet do not get the bars.

Here it is an example of the dataframes I have:

```
    ae_attendances_df <- structure(list(Gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", "Male", "Not Specified"
), class = "factor"), AgeBand = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("0 yrs", 
"1-4 yrs", "10-14 yrs", "15-19 yrs", "20-24 yrs", "25-29 yrs", 
"30-34 yrs", "35-39 yrs", "40-44 yrs", "45-49 yrs", "5-9 yrs", 
"50-54 yrs", "55-59 yrs", "60-64 yrs", "65-69 yrs", "70-74 yrs", 
"75-79 yrs", "80-84 yrs", "85+ yrs"), class = "factor"), Attend = c(4708L, 
7065L, 1914L, 2292L, 4612L, 4968L, 5620L, 4007L, 2802L, 2429L, 
2652L, 1908L, 1474L, 1414L, 1462L, 1388L, 1468L, 1586L, 4149L, 
6720L, 10781L, 2911L, 1492L, 2666L, 3565L, 3163L, 2880L, 3007L, 
4000L, 5167L), Attendances_Gender = c("Female_not_admitted", 
"Female_not_admitted", "Female_not_admitted", "Female_not_admitted", 
"Female_not_admitted", "Female_not_admitted", "Female_not_admitted", 
"Female_not_admitted", "Female_not_admitted", "Female_not_admitted", 
"Female_not_admitted", "Female_not_admitted", "Female_not_admitted", 
"Female_not_admitted", "Female_not_admitted", "Female_not_admitted", 
"Female_not_admitted", "Female_not_admitted", "Female_not_admitted", 
"Male_not_admitted", "Male_not_admitted", "Male_not_admitted", 
"Male_not_admitted", "Male_not_admitted", "Male_not_admitted", 
"Male_not_admitted", "Male_not_admitted", "Male_not_admitted", 
"Male_not_admitted", "Male_not_admitted")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "Gender", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:18, 19:29), group_sizes = c(19L, 11L), biggest_group_size = 19L, labels = structure(list(
    Gender = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Female", "Male", "Not Specified"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame", vars = "Gender", drop = TRUE))
```

The second data frame:

```
ae_admissions_df <- structure(list(Gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", "Male", "Not Specified"
    ), class = "factor"), AgeBand = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
    19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("0 yrs", 
    "1-4 yrs", "10-14 yrs", "15-19 yrs", "20-24 yrs", "25-29 yrs", 
    "30-34 yrs", "35-39 yrs", "40-44 yrs", "45-49 yrs", "5-9 yrs", 
    "50-54 yrs", "55-59 yrs", "60-64 yrs", "65-69 yrs", "70-74 yrs", 
    "75-79 yrs", "80-84 yrs", "85+ yrs"), class = "factor"), Admitted = c(4352L, 
    5229L, 1145L, 1328L, 2963L, 3769L, 3475L, 2342L, 1544L, 1141L, 
    1856L, 1022L, 1072L, 1005L, 1062L, 1000L, 801L, 736L, 1030L, 
    4727L, 8072L, 1947L, 1002L, 1615L, 2231L, 1883L, 1653L, 1602L, 
    1572L, 3054L), Admissions_Gender = c("Female_admitted", "Female_admitted", 
    "Female_admitted", "Female_admitted", "Female_admitted", "Female_admitted", 
    "Female_admitted", "Female_admitted", "Female_admitted", "Female_admitted", 
    "Female_admitted", "Female_admitted", "Female_admitted", "Female_admitted", 
    "Female_admitted", "Female_admitted", "Female_admitted", "Female_admitted", 
    "Female_admitted", "Male_admitted", "Male_admitted", "Male_admitted", 
    "Male_admitted", "Male_admitted", "Male_admitted", "Male_admitted", 
    "Male_admitted", "Male_admitted", "Male_admitted", "Male_admitted"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "Gender", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
        0:18, 19:29), group_sizes = c(19L, 11L), biggest_group_size = 19L, labels = structure(list(
        Gender = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Female", "Male", "Not Specified"
        ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame", vars = "Gender", drop = TRUE))
```

This is my code:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = ae_attendances_df, aes(x = AgeBand, fill = Attendances_Gender, y = Attend), 
           stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
  geom_bar(data = ae_admissions_df, aes(x = AgeBand, fill = Admissions_Gender, y = Admitted), 
           stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.6) + 
  xlab("Age Group") +
  ylab("ED Attendances and Admissions") + 
  ggtitle("Unscheduled ED Attendance and Admission") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(15)) +
  scale_fill_manual("", values = c("Female Admitted" = "coral3", 
                                   "Female Not Admitted" = "lightcoral", 
                                   "Male Admitted" = "steelblue4", 
                                   "Male Not Admitted" = "lightblue2"))
```

What I get isn't what I want and not able to get what is needed:

[image]

But this is what I am trying to get and obviously something does not work:

[image]

Comment: Your data only has females. Are males supposed to be also in there?

Comment: Seems that everything works until your `scale_fill_manual`. Look again at your values. They are not correct. You use "Female Admitted", but I see "Female_admitted", etc. If you use the values that actually exist in your dataframe you'll solve the problem. :)

Comment: @ AntoniosK  and avid_useR - I've edited my code. Sorry about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your use of `scale_fill_manual()` try this:

```
ggplot() +
   geom_bar(data = ae_attendances_df, aes(x = AgeBand, fill = Attendances_Gender, y = Attend),
            stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
   geom_bar(data = ae_admissions_df, aes(x = AgeBand, fill = Admissions_Gender, y = Admitted),
            stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.6) +
   xlab("Age Group") +
   ylab("ED Attendances and Admissions") +
   ggtitle("Unscheduled ED Attendance and Admission") +
   theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) +
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(15)) +
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("coral3", "lightcoral"))
```

[image]

Namely, you don't need to provide names to the `scale_fill`, it will detect that automatically based on the order of your groups.

Comment: I've edited my code as obviosly, my reproduced dataframes did not capture the other category - Male

Comment: Did this work for you? I can update the photo but I would rather not if it already worked. The gist is that you would just add the colours as you want them to `values = c(...)` and let `scale_fill_manual(...)` do the rest of the work.

Comment: it did. Yet the legend shall capture the category "Female not admitted" instead of "Female_not_admitted". Additionally, the age group on x axis does not put my 5-9 barplots.

Comment: Sorry, I kept editing my answer above. And thank you a lot bk18!

Comment: bk18 thank you a lot. I have solved the issue by renaming the categories. :) Thank you again!